# Oracle Apex 5.1 run PL/SQL after button press with process

Tags: javascript, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I'm trying to update table rows without leaving the page after a button press. I found this example:

```
javascript:{
  var vGet = new htmldb_Get(null,$x('pFlowId').value,'APPLICATION_PROCESS=update_adressen',18);
  vGet.add('P18_ADRESSEN', document.getElementById('P18_ADRESSEN').value);
  vGet.get();
  vGet = null;
};
```

On this website: [How To: APEX - Run a PL/SQL procedure from a button](http://gutzmann.blogspot.nl/2009/12/how-to-apex-run-plsql-procedure-from.html)

The PL/SQL code I'm trying to run works 100% and doesn't need any parameters at the moment:

```
update orderregels set leveradressen_id = 3 where status='W';
```

The javascript is executing too.

At first I tried to run the javascript code at page 0 like the tutorial but this didn't work. This error actually showed in my debug window (Page 0 not found).

After that I switched the page to 18 where my process is located. No debug rows showed up after that so I have no clue whats going wrong.

My process is located at this location (page 18):

[image: Process location]

I'm not sure if this is the right place.

What am I doing wrong? And why are there no debug messages showing up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do it that way (that blog post is from 2009!) use a dynamic action instead.  Create a Dynamic Action that fires when the button is pressed and execute a piece of PL/SQL code (your update statement).

Comment: Thanks alot! I didn't know this was even possible in apex. But now I'm facing a new problem: my select list isn't updated in PL/SQL when firing the dynamic action. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Add another action after the PL/SQL to refresh the item?